# Nested loop to transform MongoDB results

Tags: javascript, array, json, lodash.js

I have the following structure returned from MongoDB:

```
[Class]
    0:Class // -> this.data.userInfo as seen below in the code
        _id: "ksihHTAjdhsA9"
        createdAt:Tue Mar 29 2016 13:03:45 GMT-0400 (EDT)
        weightData: Array[3]
            0: Class
                name: "my name 1"
                value: "myval1"
                weight: 154
            1: Class
                name: "my name 2"
                value: "myval2"
                weight: 191
            2: Class
                name: "my name 3"
                value: "myval3"
                weight: 210
```

I need to loop through the `weightData` nested array and store the name and value in a dictionary variable to be used in a dropdown later. I have it working, however, I feel like this could be more efficient.

```
var dict = [];
_.each(this.data.userInfo, info => {
  if (info) {
    _.each(info.weightData, weightInfo => {
      dict.push({
          "name": weightInfo.name, 
          "value": weightInfo.value,
          "weight": weightInfo.weight
      });
    });
  }
});

console.log(dict);

/*
[Object, Object, Object]
    0:Object
        name: "my name 1"
        value: "myval1"
        weight: 154
    1:Object
        name: "my name 2"
        value: "myval2"
        weight: 191
    2:Object
        name: "my name 3"
        value: "myval3"
        weight: 210
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are basically doing a filter + flatMap. You can also use destructing:

```
var dict = _(this.data.userinfo).filter(Boolean).flatMap(info => {
  return info.weightdata.map(({name, value, weight}) => {
    return {name, value, weight};
  });
}).value();
```